# Force notification and other intents to always resume the most recent (topmost) activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm trying to keep a certain activity stack order intact regardless of notification intents and potentially malicious intents delivered to my app.

That is, my app can have this runtime structure:

1. [Activity C]
2. [Activity B]
3. [Main Activity A]

And even if the received intents are targeted at level 2 or 3 (activity B or the Main activity), I still want to present activity C to the user and have the back key go back to B and only on a second press to arrive the Main activity.

I am solving the problem right now by making the activities singleTop and starting each other through startActivityForResult, and updating notification in the notification bar to the topmost and with the flag: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, but I get sometimes the Main activity launched on top of the stack like this:

1. [Main Activity A]
2. [Activity C]
3. [Activity B]
4. [Main Activity A]

Is there a better way to accomplish the rigid structure desired?

Thanks

Comment: so basically u wanna clear all activity after u finish Activity C?

Comment: No, I want the order and the number of instance of the activities to remain the same, regardless of the receive intents. To keep it stack like, LIFO always.

Comment: u can try for android:launchMode